# Adding class to the UL and LI as per the level

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML mark up.

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li>
      <strong>Should be level 0</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
      <strong>Should be level 1</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
      <strong>Should be level 2</strong>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="thumbs">
    <li>
      <strong>Should be level 0 --  </strong>
    </li>
    <li>
      <strong>Should be level 1 --  </strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and  javascript:

```
var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  jQuery('ul.thumbs').each(function(){
    var newName = 'ul -level' + i;
    jQuery(this).addClass('ul-level-'+i)
      .before('<h2>'+newName+'</h2>');
    i = i+1;
  });

  jQuery('ul.thumbs li').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('li-level-'+j)
      .append('li-level-'+j);
    j = j+1;
  });
```

**[JS Bin Link](http://jsbin.com/idobi3/edit)**

But the level of the second UL LI is show different.

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through the `<li>`s in each `<ul>` separately, by putting the second `each` loop (for the `<li>`s) inside the first one.

For example:

```
var i = 0;
jQuery('ul.thumbs').each(function(){
    var newName = 'ul -level' + i;
    jQuery(this).addClass('ul-level-'+i)
        .before('<h2>'+newName+'</h2>');
    i++;

    var j = 0;
    jQuery(this).children('li').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass('li-level-'+j)
            .append('li-level-'+j);
        j++;
    });
});
```

By the way, `each` takes an index parameter, so you don't need your `i` and `j` variables:

```
jQuery('ul.thumbs').each(function(i){
    var newName = 'ul -level' + i;

    jQuery(this).addClass('ul-level-' + i)
        .before('<h2>' + newName + '</h2>')

        .children('li').each(function(j) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('li-level-' + j)
                .append('li-level-' + j);
        });
});
```

(Tested)

Comment: +1 for the edit pointing out `each`'s index parameter. I had just finished typing up an answer to point that out, but you ruined my fun.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `j` after each `ul`:

```
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  jQuery('ul.thumbs').each(function(){
    var newName = 'ul -level' + i;
    jQuery(this).addClass('ul-level-'+i)
      .before('<h2>'+newName+'</h2>');
    i = i+1;

    j = 0;
    jQuery('li', this).each(function(){
      jQuery(this).addClass('li-level-'+j)
        .append('li-level-'+j);
      j = j+1;
    });

  });
```

(Untested)

Also consider this something to do server-side.

Answer (score 0):

For each UL you should be processing the child  LI's

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

jQuery('ul.thumbs').each(function(){ 
   var newName = 'ul -level' + i;
   jQuery(this).addClass('ul-level-'+i)
    .before('<h2>'+newName+'</h2>');
   i = i+1;

   j=0;

   jQuery(this).children("li").each(
    function(){
     jQuery(this).addClass('li-level-'+j)
         .append('li-level-'+j);
         j = j+1;        
      }
   )

});
```